# How to use a function that was created inside the constructor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, function, ionic-framework

I'm creating a function inside the constructor, and it needs to be done inside the constructor, I wanted a button to activate it externally, however I have no idea how to do this.

My TypeScript

```
  private functionActive;

  constructor(){

    this.functionActive = function hello(){

      console.log('Hello world');

    };

    }   

  }

  buttonActive(event){

    this.functionActive.hello();

  }
```

Comment: What's wrong with this approach? BTW, you have an extra `)` after the function hello.

Comment: The console always returns a message saying "the hello() function does not exist"

Comment: What you did is called [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function). It should be called as `this.functionActive()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two mistakes:

1. Define the function without the extra `)`

   ```
   constructor() {
      this.functionActive = function hello() {
         console.log("Hello world");
      };
   }
   ```
2. Invoke it using the reference of the function i.e. `functionActive` and not `hello`, as it is a function expression:

   ```
   buttonActive(event) {
      this.functionActive();
   }
   ```

Comment: Now it makes sense what I'm looking for, thank you, the extra `)` it was a typo, I even edited the post for that.

Comment: I am waiting for the time that stackOverflow gives to evaluate as correct.

Answer (score 1):

If i got your problem right, here is the way to solve it :

```
private functionActive={};

  constructor(){

    this.functionActive["hello"] = function (){
      console.log('Hello world');
    }
    }   

  buttonActive(event){
    this.functionActive.hello();

  }
```

Here is the working demo : [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pu1oho)

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
  private functionActive;
  constructor(option) {
    if (option.enable)
      this.functionActive = function () {
        console.log("Hello world");
      };
  }
  buttonActive(event) {
    if (typeof this.functionActive === "function") this.functionActive();
  }
}
```